# Spring boot - task on startup preventing application interface exposure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to somehow in Spring boot application achieve some startup procedure that **blocks every exposure of endpoints** (and possibly other application public interfaces) until the startup procedure is completed?

I mean something like

```
@Component
public class MyBlockingStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {
    
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        // doing some task, calling external API, processing return values, ...
        startTask();
        // at this point app should be available for rest calls, scheduled tasks etc.
        someObject.appIsReadyToGo(); // alternatively app would be ready at the end of the method
    }
}
```

Problem with this approach of using ApplicationRunner is there might be some API calls to the server that I am unable to serve and therefore I would need to add some check at every API endpoint to prevent this. Or, alternatively, create some interceptor that would "block" all public communication and which would probably read some property from some service which tells it if app is ready or not. But thats not the approach I would like and I wonder if Spring implemented this somehow.

Comment: If you are running your app in kubernetes or any container manager, maybe you could use the readness probe. Is that an option to you?

Comment: @FelipeBonfante yea, might be and I considered this option but I was curious if this could be solved in spring ecosystem more easily. Plus this solution limits this use case to kube environment mostly and might not work in future if this technology changes

Comment: Spring Boot eco system has Spring Boot Actuator, so you can use `actuator/health/liveness` and `/actuator/health/readiness` endpoints. Configuration of it depends on Spring version

Answer (score 1):

If it is acceptable to run your start-up tasks before the web server instance has started at all, you could use `SmartLifecycle` to add a start task.

```java
@Component
class MyStartup implements SmartLifecycle {

    private final ServletWebServerApplicationContext ctx;
    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyStartup.class);

    @Autowired
    MyStartup(ServletWebServerApplicationContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        logger.info("doing start stuff: " + ctx.getWebServer());
        startTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {}

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPhase() {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Because the task runs before the web server has started (rather than blocking access) this might be a different approach.